# Connection between two servers using Laravel (Sockets)

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, websocket

I want to have a central server and other client servers that all connect to the central server, everything using PHP with Laravel

I tried using sockets in Laravel with laravel-websockets package, but can't find a way to do that server-to-server, without the need of any frontend like Laravel echo (which is a JavaScript package).